# Drawing a Square - Android

Tags: android, canvas, shapes

I'm trying to draw a simple square using canvas in android. The canvas is spread through the whole screen.

My code is -

```
canvas.drawRect(200, 200, 700, 700, paint);
```

(It's hard coded for testings)

but the result does not look like a square at all (the height seems to be larger than the width).

Is my logic wrong?

Here's a screenshot of the result.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The square is the black box right? Not the whole image?

Comment: try with canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 200, 200, paint); see you are getting desired results for testing and idea purpose

Comment: Yeah, the rectangle  is the black box. @Rajen -  I've tried with your values, but it still doesn't look like a square.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a device with different dpi in horizontal and vertical direction? If so, you would need to consider this difference for a perfect square.

You can get the dpi for both directions with the DisplayMetrics (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html) fields "xdpi" and "ydpi". You then should be able to create a perfect square by using a width of "X" and as height ("X" * (ydpi / xdpi)).

**Example:** for a square with 100px on each side, with 200dpi horizontally (xdpi) and 100dpi vertically (ydpi), you would need to draw a rectangle 100px wide and (100 * (100/200)) = 50px high.